# ALTER EXTENSION ... UPDATE via psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

While trying to update postgis from python with pyscopg2 the following have no effect:

```
import psycopg2.extensions

DB = "mydb"
UPDATE = "ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;"

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={}".format(DB))
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(UPDATE)
print(cur.statusmessage)
for notice in conn.notices:
    print(notice)
cur.close()
```

However updating via command line psql does update the extension:

```
$ psql -d mydb -c "ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;"
```

How can I update extensions from python without using psql?

Comment: you sure `conn.notices` will have all stdout and sterrr?..

Comment: I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `con.commit()`

Common mistake.